# What is the meaning of "A handful of might is better than a bagful of right"?

Tags: meaning

I am reading *The story of philosophy* by Will Durant. I don't understand the meaning of this sentence in page 17.

> A handful of might is better than a bagful of right.

In Cambridge Dictionary, "might" is "power, strength or force" and "right" is "the fact that a person or animal can expect to be treated in a fair, morally acceptable, or legal way, or to have the things that are necessary for life". I still can't get it. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Have you tried Googling it, and looking up "might" in a dictionary? Please indicate your research so far.

Comment: Wikipedia: [***Might makes right.***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_makes_right#:~:text=Might%20makes%20right%20or%20Might,is%20written%20by%20the%20victors%22.)

Comment: You have the wrong definition of "right". Try: "morally good, justified, or acceptable".

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check it again.

Comment: Broadly, that says that when they come face to face, the sword is much more mighty than the pen.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the meaning of the sentence from Will Durant now.